Does the Wedge Operator (^) have some meaning in Linear Programming?
I'm reading about the Cassowary algorithm - it's an iterative algorithm which draws heavily on the simplex algorithm and Linear Programming.
While reading the paper, I keep encountering the wedge operator/notation but am not too sure what it means, making the paper difficult to understand. Moreover it seems like it's used slightly differently each time.
Does the Wedge symbol have some meaning in Linear Programming? I've included some examples below with the symbol underlined in red.
Any help is appreciated. Thank You.
Example 1
Example2
Example3

The wedge $\land$ is a logical "and" operator; in all cases, it indicates that both (or all) of the given constraints must hold at the same time. For example, when we write the constraint $C$ as $C_U \land C_S \land C_I$, we split it up into three sub-constraints $C_U$, $C_S$, and $C_I$ and ask for  all three sub-constraints to hold.
The typesetting does not always cooperate. I think the later example $$\bigwedge_{i=1}^n x_i \; = \; c_i + \sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij} y_j \land \bigwedge_{i=1}^n x_i \ge 0 \land \bigwedge_{j=1}^m y_j \ge 0$$ with the unfortunate spacing around the first $=$ is especially hard to parse. We must interpret it as
$$
   \bigwedge_{i=1}^n\left(x_i = c_i + \sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij}y_j\right) \; \land \; \bigwedge_{i=1}^n \Big( x_i \ge 0 \Big) \; \land \; \bigwedge_{j=1}^m \Big( y_j \ge 0\Big).
$$
In other words, there are three types of linear constraints on this optimization problem. There are $n$ constraints of the form $$x_i = c_i + \sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij}y_j$$ for $i=1, \dots, n$, there are nonegativity constraints on $x_1, \dots, x_n$, and there are nonnegativity constraints on $y_1, \dots, y_m$.

Awesome, this makes sense. Thank You.
